# Grouping pandas dataframe on fewer timestamps (index)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have data that I do groupby on the timestamp to perform various calculations. The timestamps are approximately every 30 seconds to 1 minute. If I use 2 years worth of data, it becomes way too much data. Is there a way I can make groups on timestamps but only sample timestamps that are 1 hour apart? I looked into resampling but it requires an aggregation function. I just want less number of dataframe groups.

```
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6693.1     0.066     6693.0     2.443      0
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6817.0     0.181     6589.0     0.450     99
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6694.4     0.150     6689.4     0.180      1
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6699.0     1.100     6679.6     0.001     11
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6702.7     0.580     6677.9     8.000     15
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6704.6     6.000     6669.0    12.900     22
2018-09-23 17:45:54+00:00     6715.0     0.990     6653.9     0.045     37

2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6770.6     6.881     6624.0     0.250     64
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6770.9     0.003     6623.4     3.894     65
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6750.0     0.100     6635.7     1.090     50
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6786.0    10.000     6605.3     0.422     78
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6698.0     0.222     6685.0     1.000      7
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6718.1     1.050     6653.9     0.045     37
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6694.8     0.213     6687.3     2.988      1
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6693.1     1.196     6693.0     2.443      0
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6820.0     0.149     6590.1     0.695     99
2018-09-23 17:47:18+00:00     6704.6     6.000     6670.0     0.139     22

2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6765.0     0.008     6630.6     0.180     61
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6703.8     8.000     6675.0     0.100     21
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6710.2     0.165     6665.3     5.000     29
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6776.3    13.372     6618.9     1.500     74
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6770.0     1.015     6626.1     0.051     66
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6693.4     0.360     6688.5     2.988      1
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6741.1     0.100     6640.0     2.000     50
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6768.0     6.153     6627.7     0.810     64
2018-09-23 17:48:45+00:00     6769.0     0.500     6627.0     0.043     65
```

Comment: why not just `df.resample('1H').first()`.

Comment: I want the entire chunk (group) but sampled less frequently. For example, I want the entire group of 17:45:54+00:00 but I don't want 17:47:18+00:00.

Comment: Can you post your exact desired output? How do you decide that you want `17:45:54+00:00` but not `17:47:18+00:00`. They are only 2 minutes apart, correct?

Comment: correct. I didn't post all the data but imagine I have hundreds of thousands of these groups, 1-2 mins apart. I want to reduce it to like X mins apart which I can decide on later. Right now I'm doing df[df.index.minutes%5==0] and seems to be doing alright for 5 mins apart.